# Parties distribution - Probability theorem

Tags: probability

I'm studying probability by myself before university, and I got this question in my book which I'm not sure I'm getting right -

The number of times a person goes to a party on Monday distributes uniformly $U(2,15)$. The number of times a person goes to a party on Wednesday distributes $Bin(15,0.2)$. What is the E(x) of the number of parties that the person is going to?

So I understand that the E(x) on binomial distribution is $3$ $(15*0.2)$. In the uniform distribution, it's $8.5$ $((2+15)/2)$. How do I combine between the two means? just add them together?

Comment: Yes, $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$

Comment: If you like one of the given answer it is standard to accept it $\left( \color{limegreen}{\checkmark} \right)$.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called linearity of expectation. It can be easily proven that $\mathbf{E}[X+Y] = \mathbf{E}[X] + \mathbf{E}[Y]$ even when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.